# Getting user input in java game

Tags: java, input

I am creating a game using Java, initially the user is presented with a screen where they  need to enter a name. They then press enter and the name entered will be displayed during the game.
The name input screen consists of 2 images drawn using `g.drawImage(image,x,y);`

What's the best way to add a text input field of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on a JFrame, you can use a [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).
If it's on an applet, you can use an [Applet TextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html)

Comment: Its an applet, ive tried adding the TextField using add(TextField); but its not appearing on the screen.

Comment: JTextField is also usable in JApplets.

Comment: @OliverBennett Please post a small example of code that illustrates what you have tried. Describe what happens when you run the code and how it differs from what you want to happen.

Comment: Ah i've got it to appear now, forgot to add "TextField.setBounds(20,70,100,40);"